# SQL query that returns records with certain NULL values when WHERE does not match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running the following query in Postgres:

```
SELECT  raw_times.*, efforts.id as effort_id, efforts.event_id as event_id, splits.id as split_id 
FROM raw_times 
INNER JOIN event_groups ON event_groups.id = raw_times.event_group_id 
INNER JOIN events ON events.event_group_id = event_groups.id 
INNER JOIN efforts ON efforts.event_id = events.id 
INNER JOIN aid_stations ON aid_stations.event_id = events.id 
INNER JOIN splits ON splits.id = aid_stations.split_id 
WHERE efforts.bib_number::text = raw_times.bib_number
    AND splits.parameterized_base_name = raw_times.parameterized_split_name
```

The idea is to locate matching bib numbers and split names and to return raw_time records with various relation ids populated.

In plain English, the logic works like this: For each raw_time, check the event_group_id. An event_group has many events, and an event has many efforts, and the efforts table has a bib_number column. Bib number is unique within an event_group, but is not unique within the entire efforts table.

So for each raw_time, because we know the event_group_id and the bib_number, we can determine which effort it relates to. Knowing the effort allows us also to know the event (because an effort has an event_id).

An event has many splits through the aid_stations join table. Split name is unique within an event. Because we know the event (determined as described above) and we know the split name (it is a column on the raw_times table) we can determine the split_id.

The query works as expected for records where there is a matching bib number and split name. But for records where either the bib number or split name does not match, the WHERE clause is not satisfied, so the raw_time record is not returned at all.

I've tried the query with LEFT JOIN in place of each INNER JOIN, but I get the same result.

What I'd like is for all raw_time records to be returned, but if there is no matching split name, return the record with NULL for the split_id, and if there is no matching bib number, return the record with NULL for effort_id, event_id, and split_id.

The raw_times table looks like this:

```
id  event_group_id  parameterized_split_name  bib_number
3        53         finish                    11
4        53         finish                    603
5        53         finish                    9999
6        53         nonexistent               603
```

The event_groups table looks like this:

```
id
53
51
```

The events table looks like this:

```
id  event_group_id
26  53
28  53
18  51
```

The efforts table looks like this:

```
id      event_id  bib_number
22183   26        11
22400   28        603
5747    18        11
```

The aid_stations table looks like this:

```
id   event_id  split_id
236  26        30
237  26        31
238  26        106
239  26        111
240  26        112
241  26        109
242  26        113
254  28        119
255  28        118
138  18        1
150  18        16
```

The splits table looks like this:

```
id  parameterized_base_name
30  finish
31  start
106 aid-1
109 aid-4
111 aid-2
112 aid-3
113 aid-5
118 start
119 finish
1   start
16  finish
```

The query should return this:

```
id  event_group_id parameterized_split_name bib_number effort_id event_id  split_id
3   53             finish                   11         22183     26        30
4   53             finish                   603        22400     28        119
6   53             nonexistent              603        22400     28        NULL
5   53             finish                   9999       NULL      NULL      NULL
```

Here's a link to the ERD: https://github.com/SplitTime/OpenSplitTime/blob/master/erd.pdf

Comment: To solve your immediate issue (an optional join), the solution is definitely to use an outer join (i.e. `LEFT JOIN`) with the join inside the `ON` part.

Comment: To assist it really helps to have a relationship diagram - a picture of all tables and their relationships - most importantly the one-to-many aspects of the relationships. When you join tables that are effectively many-many you get "double counting"

Comment: PS I checked out your site - looks pretty awesome.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for your comments and kind words. I added a link to the ERD in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through the advantage of having sample data and wanted result, the "missing element" seems to be the need for a limited result via a correlated subquery for the split_id.

See this working in PostgreSQL 9.6 at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/NOEHF96092)

```
CREATE TABLE raw_times
    (id int, event_group_id int, parameterized_split_name varchar(11), bib_number int)
;

INSERT INTO raw_times
    (id, event_group_id, parameterized_split_name, bib_number)
VALUES
    (3, 53, 'finish', 11),
    (4, 53, 'finish', 603),
    (5, 53, 'finish', 9999),
    (6, 53, 'nonexistent', 603)
;


CREATE TABLE event_groups
    (id int)
;

INSERT INTO event_groups
    (id)
VALUES
    (53)
;


CREATE TABLE efforts
    (id int, event_id int, bib_number int)
;

INSERT INTO efforts
    (id, event_id, bib_number)
VALUES
    (22183, 26, 11),
    (22400, 28, 603)
;


CREATE TABLE aid_stations
    (id int, event_id int, split_id int)
;

INSERT INTO aid_stations
    (id, event_id, split_id)
VALUES
    (236, 26, 30),
    (237, 26, 31),
    (238, 26, 106),
    (239, 26, 111),
    (240, 26, 112),
    (241, 26, 109),
    (242, 26, 113),
    (254, 28, 119),
    (255, 28, 118)
;


CREATE TABLE splits
    (id int, parameterized_base_name varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO splits
    (id, parameterized_base_name)
VALUES
    (30, 'finish'),
    (31, 'start'),
    (106, 'aid-1'),
    (109, 'aid-4'),
    (111, 'aid-2'),
    (112, 'aid-3'),
    (113, 'aid-5'),
    (118, 'start'),
    (119, 'finish')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
     r.id, r.event_group_id, r.parameterized_split_name, r.bib_number
   , e.id as effort_id
   , e.event_id
   , s.split_id
from raw_times r
left join (
            select ef.id, ef.event_id, ef.bib_number, ev.event_group_id
            from efforts ef
            inner join events ev on ef.event_id = ev.id
           ) e on r.bib_number = e.bib_number
               and e.event_group_id = r.event_group_id
left join lateral (
            select a.split_id from aid_stations a
            inner join splits s on a.split_id = s.id
            where a.event_id = e.event_id
            and s.parameterized_base_name = r.parameterized_split_name
            limit 1) s on true
order by r.bib_number, r.id
;
```

**Results**:

```
| id | event_group_id | parameterized_split_name | bib_number | effort_id | event_id | split_id |
|----|----------------|--------------------------|------------|-----------|----------|----------|
|  3 |             53 |                   finish |         11 |     22183 |       26 |       30 |
|  4 |             53 |                   finish |        603 |     22400 |       28 |      119 |
|  6 |             53 |              nonexistent |        603 |     22400 |       28 |   (null) |
|  5 |             53 |                   finish |       9999 |    (null) |   (null) |   (null) |
```

Note. If using a an older version of Postgres then the correlated subquery can be used within the select clause in lieu of the `left join lateral` seen above.

Comment: OK, this is interesting. But I'm getting different results because bib_number is not unique in the efforts table. It is only unique within efforts for events within an event_group. In my actual (non-redacted) database, there are many efforts having duplicate bib_numbers, and these duplicates show up unwanted when using this query. Is there a way to limit this?

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing in this query where raw_time.parameterized_split_name is being matched to split.parameterized_base_name. We can't just take the first split ordered by id. I appreciate your help and would love to see your further thoughts.

Comment: query has been revised

Comment: This is a significant improvement. I can see, however, that I need to add some additional data to better represent the real database. I've edited the question, and you'll see that the result returns some unwanted data. Could you take another look in light of the additional data?

Comment: I've also updated the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a5f2e5/1) to show the changes. You will see that the raw_time with id 3 is now being repeated in the query result, with an unwanted/unrelated set of split_id, effort_id, and event_id.

Comment: I believe I've found a solution. Please see the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a54022/2) and let me know what you think. Feel free to improve on the code. If you want to incorporate it, please do so and I'll mark your answer as correct. Also, I am using Postgres 9.6, so would be interested in how to refactor the subquery using `left join lateral`.

Comment: Revised answer for Postgres 9.6 with `left join lateral` and different approach to use of events table  in the joins.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, add the condition while doing the LEFT OUTER join.

```
SELECT  raw_times.*, efforts.id as effort_id, efforts.event_id as event_id, splits.id as split_id 
FROM raw_times 
INNER JOIN event_groups ON event_groups.id = raw_times.event_group_id 
INNER JOIN events ON events.event_group_id = event_groups.id 
LEFT JOIN efforts ON efforts.event_id = events.id AND efforts.bib_number::text = raw_times.bib_number
INNER JOIN aid_stations ON aid_stations.event_id = events.id 
LEFT JOIN splits ON splits.id = aid_stations.split_id AND splits.parameterized_base_name = raw_times.parameterized_split_name
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT  raw_times.*, efforts.id as effort_id, efforts.event_id as event_id, splits.id as split_id 
FROM raw_times 
INNER JOIN event_groups ON event_groups.id = raw_times.event_group_id 
INNER JOIN events ON events.event_group_id = event_groups.id 
LEFT JOIN efforts ON efforts.event_id = events.id 
INNER JOIN aid_stations ON aid_stations.event_id = events.id 
LEFT JOIN splits ON splits.id = aid_stations.split_id 
WHERE (efforts.bib_number::text = raw_times.bib_number OR efforts.event_id IS NULL)
    AND (splits.parameterized_base_name = raw_times.parameterized_split_name OR splits.id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Sorry for the formatting as I am commenting from cell phone, not system.

Comment: In my database I currently have 6 raw_time records. This query results in each raw_time record being returned 9 times (total of 54 records) with various results in the effort_id, event_id, and split_id columns. I tried with `SELECT DISTINCT ON (raw_times.id)` but this returns random results, most of which are wrong.

Comment: There is an issue with the join conditions you have added. You can add a “Distinct” on top for the time being. BTW, did this solve the performance issue?

Comment: Per my earlier comment, adding DISTINCT does not fix the problem. Not sure which performance issue you are referring to?

Comment: Without sample data how can we "see" anything? It is unreasonable to criticize  those helping without the benefit of access to data, or the expected result. I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @moveson - pardon me, i was mixed up with another question on the site. If I understand you correctly, you want to do filtering on split name and bib number only when the values from the corresponding tables are non-null. I hope I was able to understand the conditions. Have added an EDIT.

Comment: @SouravA Thank you so much for your answers. Unfortunately the edited answer results in the same issue as my solution; that is to say, the records without a match do not show up at all. Is there an easy way for me to make a copy of my database available to you?

Comment: Hi, I accidentally did an inner join instead of left with (efforts) and (split). Could you please try the EDIT again?

Comment: @SouravA Just tried again with the same result as before.

Comment: Ok, let’s try again. As per you, “What I'd like is for all raw_time records to be returned, but if there is no matching split name, return the record with NULL for the split_id, and if there is no matching bib number, return the record with NULL for effort_id, event_id, and split_id.” Have you thought of joining on split name and bib number respectively i.e. change the join keys?

Comment: I am saying as you basically want to see if these columns match, and if they don’t, you want to return null- seems like you should be LEFT joining on these columns.

Comment: @SouravA I'm open to joining on split name and bib number. I played around with that a bit, but didn't have any luck. I agree with the LEFT JOIN strategy--just don't know how to implement it. Keep in mind that parameterized_split_name is not unique.

Comment: Ok..so which query did you use? Probably I can help. And also, some examples wrt data might help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169128/discussion-between-moveson-and-sourava).

Comment: @Used_By_Already My apologies. I've added minimal and complete data with the desired result. Your thoughts would be appreciated.